# Solving the given recurrence relation by substitution

Tags: recurrence-relations

The problem

> $T(n)=2T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)+\log{n}$
>     $T(1)=1$

I was able to come up with the solution $\Theta{(n)}$ using Master theorem. But I want to get the same solution using expansion or I guess this is also called as substitution method. I have tried following:

$T(n)=2T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)+\log{n}$
$=2\left[2T\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)+\log\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) \right] +\log{n}$
$=4T\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)+2\log\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)+\log{\left(n\right)}$
$=4\left[2T\left(\frac{n}{8}\right)+\log\left(\frac{n}{4}\right) \right]+2\log\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)+\log{\left(n\right)}$
$=8T\left(\frac{n}{8}\right)+4\log\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)+2\log\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)+\log{\left(n\right)}$
$=16T\left(\frac{n}{16}\right)+8\log\left(\frac{n}{8}\right)+4\log\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)+2\log\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)+\log{\left(n\right)}$
$=16T\left(\frac{n}{16}\right)
+8\left[\log\left(n\right)-\log\left(8\right)\right]
+4\left[\log\left(n\right)-\log\left(4\right)\right]
+2\left[\log\left(n\right)-\log\left(2\right)\right]
+\log{\left(n\right)}$
$=16T\left(\frac{n}{16}\right)
+8\log\left(n\right)-8\times 3
+4\log\left(n\right)-4\times 2
+2\log\left(n\right)-2\times 1
+\log{\left(n\right)}$
$=16T\left(\frac{n}{16}\right)
+\left[8\log\left(n\right)
+4\log\left(n\right)
+2\log\left(n\right)
+\log{\left(n\right)}\right]
-\left[8\times 3+4\times 2+2\times 1\right]$

The recurrence terminates at $\frac{n}{2^k}=1$. So, we can generalize this as follows:

$T(n)=2^kT\left(\frac{n}{2^k}\right)
+\left[2^{k-1}\log\left(n\right)
+2^{k-2}\log\left(n\right)
+...
+2^1\log\left(n\right)
+2^0\log{\left(n\right)}\right]
-\left[(2^{k-1}\times k-1)+(2^{k-2}\times k-2)+...+(2^1\times 1)+(2^0\times 0)\right]
$

$T(n)=2^kT\left(1\right)
+\left[(2^k-1)\log\left(n\right)\right]
-\left[(2^{k-1}\times k-1)+(2^{k-2}\times k-2)+...+(2^1\times 1)+(2^0\times 0)\right]
$

I am stuck here. I dont feel this is leading me to $\Theta\left(n\right)$. Is it so? Is this problem unsolvable by this approach?

(**PS:** I very well welcome other approaches people are suggesting in the solutions and comments. They are really really great and keep them coming. But I also want to know whether I was doing it wrong absolutely and whether it can be solved further following my path.)

Comment: If you look at $n=1,2,4,8,16,32,\ldots$ then you get $T(n)=1,3,8,19,42,89\ldots$ with the values slightly more than doubling each time and you can then find [this suggests](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C3%2C8%2C19%2C42%2C89&sort=&language=&go=Search) $T(2^m)=3 \times 2^m -m-2$ which you can then prove satisfies the recurrence, suggesting $T(n)=3n-\log_2(n)-2$ more generally and this is $\Theta(n)$

Answer (score 1):

If you keep on developing you get

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
& & T(2^k) = 2T(2^{k-1})+k = 2\big(2T(2^{k-2})+(k-1)\big)+k = \cdots \\
& & k + 2(k-1) + 2^2(k-2)+\ldots+ 2^{k-1}\cdot 1 = \\
& & 2^k\sum_{i=1}^{k} \frac{i}{2^i} \to 2^k\cdot C
\end{eqnarray}
$$

for a constant $C=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{i}{2^i}$ (which you can work out exactly if you care, but there is no need). So $T(2^k)=\Theta(2^k)$ and so $T(n)=\Theta(n)$.

It is always solvable by this approach because this is exactly the proof of the master theorem.

Comment: Super thanks. That looks very easy and proper and looks different from what I did (a mess?). But was I doing it all wrong (because I have solved many problems by this approach, so was just guessing where did I go wrong)?

Comment: You were doing it all OK. You just have to remember that $\log{n}\approx k$ so in the last formula there will be some cancellations.

Answer (score 0):

As long as $n = 2^m$ and $T(1) = 1$ we have

$$
T(2^m) = 2^m + \log(2^m)+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}2^{n-k}\log(2^k)
$$

because

$$
n = 1\to T(2^1) = 2^2+\log(2^1)\\
n = 2\to T(2^2) = 2^2+\log(2^2) + 2^1\log(2^1)\\
n = 3\to T(2^3) = 2^3 + \log(2^3) + 2^2\log(2^1)+ 2^1\log(2^2)\\
\cdots
$$